# JavaScript Mouseover gallery works in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a gallery which is shown on "mouseover". It enlarges a thumbnail in the centre of the screen. This is done with  JavaScript.

The problem is that it works in IE but not with Chrome.

Here's the code:

```html
<center>
  <a name="whenCara">
  </a>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <fieldset id="javaScriptSet">
          <legend>
            <img src="Images/gallery.png">
            </img>
          </legend>
          <div class="preview" align="center">
            <img id="preview" src="Images2/1.jpg" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="thumbnails">
            <label>
              <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="Images2/1.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            </label>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="Images2/2.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="Images2/3.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="Images2/4.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="Images2/5.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="Images2/6.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img7.src" id="img7" src="Images2/7.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img8.src" id="img8" src="Images2/8.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img9.src" id="img9" src="Images2/9.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img10.src" id="img10" src="Images2/10.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img11.src" id="img11" src="Images2/11.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img12.src" id="img12" src="Images2/12.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img13.src" id="img13" src="Images2/13.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img14.src" id="img14" src="Images2/14.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img15.src" id="img15" src="Images2/15.jpg"     alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
      </div>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    </center>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can someone help if you don't post the JS code?

Comment: It's all there, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are closing the tags on the wrong position. IE is ignoring that but Chrome doesn't (untested).

Pay attention to the last section:

Wrong:

```
    </center>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Right:

```
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
    </center>
```

Here's the code which should work:

```html
<center>
  <a name="whenCara">
  </a>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <fieldset id="javaScriptSet">
          <legend>
            <img src="Images/gallery.png" />
          </legend>
          <div class="preview" align="center">
            <img id="preview" src="Images2/1.jpg" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="thumbnails">
            <label>
              <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="Images2/1.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            </label>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="Images2/2.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="Images2/3.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="Images2/4.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="Images2/5.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="Images2/6.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img7.src" id="img7" src="Images2/7.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img8.src" id="img8" src="Images2/8.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img9.src" id="img9" src="Images2/9.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img10.src" id="img10" src="Images2/10.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img11.src" id="img11" src="Images2/11.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img12.src" id="img12" src="Images2/12.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img13.src" id="img13" src="Images2/13.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img14.src" id="img14" src="Images2/14.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
            <img onmouseover="preview.src=img15.src" id="img15" src="Images2/15.jpg"     alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
      </div>
        <br>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

A previous poster who's comment has been deleted was correct.

In Chrome I had to use getElementById, so the correct syntax was:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img15').src"
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster and neater solution:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=this.src"
```